# Want to login using spring security with Email OR mobile number

Tags: java, spring, spring-social

Want to login using Email OR mobile number using spring security.

Here is my code:--

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd">

    <http pattern="/admin" security="none" /> 

    <http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">

        <intercept-url pattern="/admin*" access="hasRole('SYS_ADMIN')" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/cab-stop-admin*" access="hasAnyRole('SYS_ADMIN','CABSTOP_ADMIN')" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/driver*" access="hasAnyRole('DRIVER','SYS_ADMIN','CABSTOP_ADMIN')" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/customer*" access="hasAnyRole('CUSTOMER','SYS_ADMIN','CABSTOP_ADMIN')" />

        <form-login login-page="/login" default-target-url="/role-check"
            authentication-failure-url="/login?error=true" />
            <remember-me key="_spring_security_remember_me" data-source-ref="fmsDataSource" authentication-success-handler-ref="loginSuccessHandler"/>
        <logout logout-success-url="/" />
        <access-denied-handler error-page="/login"/>
         </http> 
         <beans:bean id="loginSuccessHandler" class="com.cabfms.authentication.LoginSuccessHandler"></beans:bean>
         <authentication-manager> 
        <authentication-provider> 
         <!-- <password-encoder hash="md5"  />  -->
        <jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="fmsDataSource"  
        users-by-username-query="select Email,Password, 'true' as enabled from login_details where Is_Blocked = 'N' and Deleted='N' and Email=?"
        authorities-by-username-query="select u.Email, ur.Role_Name from login_details u, role_master ur where u.Role_Master_Id = ur.Role_Master_Id and u.Email =?" />
    </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>
</beans:beans>
```

In this code I have a query like

```
select Email,Password, 'true' as enabled from login_details where Is_Blocked = 'N' and Deleted='N' and Email=?
```

where I match only email but I want to match mobile number also.** means I want to match Email OR Mobile number (Any One) because I pass any one from tha JSP (Email OR Mobile)

So please Suggest your answer

Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 2):

How does your JSP look like? Do you have a form with a `j_username` or are using two separate fields for email and mobile?

If you're passing both you'll have to implement your own authentication manager. The concrete user details service used by Spring Security when you declare `jdbc-user-service>` is a `JdbcDaoImpl` which implements `UserDetailsService`. That interface has a `loadUserByUsername(String)` method which obviously only accepts a username.

If you want to allow your users to enter either email or mobile in a *single* text input named `j_username` it might work if your query is

```
... where Is_Blocked = 'N' and Deleted='N' and (Email=? or Mobile=?)
```